# Find Maclaurin series for$f(x) = \frac{2x}{1-5x^3}$

Tags: taylor-expansion

I'm trying to find the Maclaurin series for $f(x) = \frac{2x}{1-5x^3}$, but my solution is different from what I know it supposed to be, which is $2x+10x^4+50x^7+250x^{10}+...$
This is my attempt:

$$f(x) = \frac{2x}{1-5x^3}$$
$$\frac{1}{1-x} = 1+x+x^2+x^3+...$$ 
$$\frac{2x}{1-x}=2x+2x^2+2x^3+2x^4+...\tag{multiply both sides by $x$}$$
$$\frac{2x}{1-5x^3}=10x^3+50x^6+250x^9+625x^{12}+...\tag{substitute $x$ with $5x^3$}$$
Where is my mistake?

Comment: You forgot to also substitute the $x$ on the numerator.

Comment: The mistake may lie in writing $\frac{1}{1-x}=1+x+x^2+\cdots$. Oh, this is true enough, but you should have written $\frac{1}{1-t}=1+t+t^2+t^3+\cdots$.  Then the substitution process is less likely to lead to oversights.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: Why is that?

Comment: Because the presence of $x$ in $1+x+x^2+\cdots$ led you to substitute $5x^3$ every time you saw $x$, icluding the $x$ in the numerator. If you write your expression as $2x(1+t+t^2+\cdots)$, you will do the substitution correctly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is that you should first substitute, then multiply. Else, you're forgetting to substitute in the $2x$ term.

Comment: I got the right answer now, but why do you have to substitute first and only then multiply?

Comment: @wizardo Because substituting after multiplying forces you to change the term $2x$, which you want to keep. You cannot change just the $x$s you wish, you need to apply the change to all the terms containing an $x$ in the left hand side, do you see?

Comment: Yeah, I get it now, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

The substitution $x\rightarrow 5x^3$ changes $\frac{2x}{1-x}$ to $\frac{10x^3}{1-5x^3}$.

Answer (score 1):

You might get into less complication if you use summation notation:

$$\frac{1}{1-u}  =  \Sigma_{k=0}^{\infty} u^k  \rightarrow \frac{2x}{1-(5x^3)}  =  2x \cdot \frac{1}{1-(5x^3)}  =  2x \cdot\Sigma_{k=0}^{\infty} (5x^3)^k   $$

$$=  2x \cdot\Sigma_{k=0}^{\infty} 5^k \cdot x^{3k}  =  \Sigma_{k=0}^{\infty} 2 \cdot 5^k \cdot x^{3k+1}  . $$